# Firefox addon cannot recognize new version on Update.rdf file

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, rdf, add-on

I used [McCoy tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/McCoy) to "Install" my install.rdf file and sign my update.rdf file.

On my `Install.rdf` file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"
         xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#"
         xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$e2DK."
                   em:id="{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}"
                   em:minVersion="4.0"
                   em:maxVersion="15.*" />
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest"
                   em:id="{ext-id}"
                   em:type="2"
                   em:name="Ext X"
                   em:version="1.0.4"
                   em:description="..."
                   em:creator="Bruno Leonardo Michels"
                   em:updateURL="http://www.example.com/dl/update.rdf"
                   em:bootstrap="false"
                   em:updateKey="xxx">
    <em:targetApplication RDF:resource="rdf:#$e2DK."/>
  </RDF:Description>
</RDF:RDF>
```

On my `Update.rdf` file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF:RDF xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"
         xmlns:NC="http://home.netscape.com/NC-rdf#"
         xmlns:RDF="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$D1abg"
                   em:version="1.0.4">
    <em:targetApplication RDF:resource="rdf:#$G1abg"/>
  </RDF:Description>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$G1abg"
                   em:id="{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}"
                   em:minVersion="4.0"
                   em:maxVersion="15.*"
                   em:updateLink="http://www.example.com/dl/ext.xpi"
                   em:updateInfoURL="http://www.example.com/dl/ext.txt" />
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$M1abg"
                   em:version="1.0.3">
    <em:targetApplication RDF:resource="rdf:#$P1abg"/>
  </RDF:Description>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mozilla:extension:{ext-id}"
                   em:signature="xxx">
    <em:updates RDF:resource="rdf:#$C1abg"/>
  </RDF:Description>
  <RDF:Seq RDF:about="rdf:#$C1abg">
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="rdf:#$D1abg"/>
    <RDF:li RDF:resource="rdf:#$M1abg"/>
  </RDF:Seq>
  <RDF:Description RDF:about="rdf:#$P1abg"
                   em:id="{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}"
                   em:minVersion="4.0"
                   em:maxVersion="15.*"
                   em:updateLink="http://www.example.com/dl/ext103.xpi"
                   em:updateInfoURL="http://www.example.com/dl/ext.txt" />
</RDF:RDF>
```

When I click "Find updates" Firefox requests the update.rdf url and retrieves the correct file with the correct version (1.0.4). But it doesn't do anything, doesn't show any updates, does not update... It just stay there with version 1.0.3...

Isn't the `em:version` what determines the addon version? What am I missing here?

To test I installed and signed a version `1.0.4` and changed the version to `1.0.3` installed and signed, so I have two versions with different numbers. I installed the version `1.0.3` and I am trying to get `1.0.4` through update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am not using `https` I have to include the `em:updateHash` under `em:updateLink` on the `update.rdf` file. I used SHA1 generated from [Hashtab](http://www.implbits.com/HashTab/HashTabWindows.aspx).

```
em:updateHash="sha1:<hash>"
```

And after adding the hash you have to sign the file again.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but already have a sha1 hash on the file so not sure what's wrong in my case. Am I right in assuming the sha1 hash is of the xpi file?